# Can the overlay option for draw in tikz be changed to behave like onslide?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

Consider the following presentation.

[image]

This presentation was generated with the following code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame \thepage}

  Page text.
  \[
    \begin{tikzpicture}

      \draw<2->[ultra thick] circle (2cm);

    \end{tikzpicture}
  \]

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This presentation is not quite what I want. I'd like the "Page text." to remain in the same place on every slide. This can be accomplished by changing `\draw<2->[ultra thick] circle (2cm);` to `\onslide<2->{\draw[ultra thick] circle (2cm);}`.

I'd like to find an alternate solution by keeping the `\draw<>` syntax. Is this possible?

For clarity, I want my presentation to look like this.

[image]

Comment: You can use the `visible on` key from the `overlay-beamer-styles` Ti*k*Z library to avoid jumps.

Comment: @abcdefg Excellent! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[t]` to top-align the contents of the frame and/or use the `visible on` key from the `overlay-beamer-styles` TikZ library to avoid jumps.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Frame \thepage}

  Page text.
  \[
    \begin{tikzpicture}

      \draw<2->[->, ultra thick] circle[radius=2cm];

    \end{tikzpicture}
  \]

\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame \thepage}

  Page text.
  \[
    \begin{tikzpicture}

      \draw[->,visible on=<2->,ultra thick] circle[radius=2cm];

    \end{tikzpicture}
  \]

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there documentation for `overlay-beamer-styles`? I have several headaches that I suspect can be solved with this library but can't easily find documentation.

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick Yes. `texdoc aobs`. Why `aobs`? Because it works. ;-)